# Acumatica Login Page Error

Tags: acumatica

We are experiencing this error if we log in to our instance of Acumatica, we think it occur because of the customization that we made that is not published properly, we can't login using our username/password so we can't fix this error, please see image:[acumaticaloginpageerror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQOOh.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually unpublish this customization by removing the HRIS.dll file or any other custom DLL from the bin folder.

Comment: hi gabriel, thanks for your answer, it really helps.